# How to bind images to a Combobox in WPF, getting the images from a lookup

Tags: wpf, image, data-binding, combobox

I have a **WPF** combobox that I would like to *bind* to an observable collection of *Teams* on my ViewModel class e.g.

```
class Team 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int CountryId { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
   public IDictionary<int, Image> CountryFlags { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to have the combobox display the flag and name of each team, what is the best way to do this?

I don't want to add the image directly to the team object if I can avoid it and would be happy to move the *CountryFlags* lookup to another class if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make a custom [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for this.  Basically, you'll want to have the converter convert from Team -> Image, and have it do the lookup within the Dictionary based on the CountryId in the Team.